# Why doesn't AngularJS $onChanges notice the array changed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

### Why doesn't angular notice the array changed, but does if I change it to null first?

I have an AngularJS component which accepts an array through a <strike>one way</strike> two-way (`=`) data binding. In the parent, I have a button whose ng-click maps to this function:

```
onClickAddValue()
{ 
    this.listOfValues.push(this.valueInput);
}
```

where `this.listOfValues` is what gets passed to the child component through a binding. This code has no effect (the child component's view is not updated). Being a smart cookie who did his homework about AngularJS beforehand, I know this is because the value of `listOfValues` hasn't changed, it's still the same object reference. So I do this:

```
onClickAddValue()
{ 
    var oldList = this.listOfValues;
    this.listOfValues = [];
    for (let value of oldList)
    {
        this.listOfValues.push(value);
    }
    this.listOfValues.push(this.valueInput);
}
```

But that doesn't work either! I also tried `Object.assign` and `angular.copy`. It's as if my child component just doesn't notice any changes to its input at all. And yet clearly it does, because the code below **does** work!

```
onClickAddValue()
{ 
    var oldList = this.listOfValues;
    this.listOfValues = null;
    setTimeout(
        () =>
        {
            this.listOfValues = oldList;
            this.listOfValues.push(this.valueInput);
            this.$scope.$digest();
        }
    );  
}
```

What's going on? I can see why the last snippet works - `listOfValues` is set to null, `ng-click` automatically triggers a digest and angular notices the new null value, so it updates the view, and then an instant later `listOfValues` is changed again, another digest is triggered manually, and the view updates again. But then why does the other version not work? Why is changing the object different to changing it to a null, and *then* changing it?

Comment: How are you consuming the array in the component? Are you using `$ngChange`? Or are you using `ng-repeat` in the template?

Comment: @georgeawg Sorry about the delay. In the child component, I'm listening for changes to to the bound `listOfValues` in `$onChanges`.

Comment: The question would have been easier to solve if you had said from the beginning that you were using two-way  (`=`) binding instead of erroneously stating that you were using one-way binding. Two-way ("=") binding should be avoided because it adds an extra watcher and it makes migration to Angular 2+ more difficult. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-based Application Architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture).

Comment: @georgeawg I say it's a two-way binding in the first line of the post.

Comment: Check the edits. Your original question said "one-way binding". I edited the question to say "two-way binding" to make it useful to other readers.

Comment: @georgeawg Oh I see. My bad, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm listening for changes to to the bound `listOfValues` in `$onChanges`

Use [Array.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to create a new object that will be detected by `$onChanges`:

```
  onClickAddValue()
  { 
    this.listOfValues.push(this.valueInput);
    this.listOfValues = this.listOfValues.concat();
  }
```

The `$onChanges` [Life-Cycle Hook](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks) only checks for *reference* changes. It does not check for *contents* changes. After changing the *contents* with `Array.push`. Use the `Array.concat` method to create a new object that will be detected by the change detector.

[The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/yTDHntizHjYWeOc8Uv5e?p=preview)

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl", class {
  constructor () {
    this.listOfValues = [3,5];
  }
  onClickAddValue()
  { 
    this.listOfValues.push(this.valueInput);
    this.listOfValues = this.listOfValues.concat();
  }
})
.component("myComponent",{
  bindings: {values: "<"},
  template: `
      <fieldset>
        {{$ctrl.values}}<br>
        changes={{$ctrl.changes}}
      </fieldset>
  `,
  controller: class {
    constructor () {
      this.changes=0;
    }
    $onChanges(ch) {
      this.changes++;
      //console.log(ch);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as $ctrl">
    <input ng-model="$ctrl.valueInput" /><br>
    <button ng-click="$ctrl.onClickAddValue()">Add value</button>
    <br>
    {{$ctrl.listOfValues}}
    <my-component values="$ctrl.listOfValues"></my-component>
</body>
```

---

### Update

> Having done some more playing around, I think this actually has to do with the fact that `listOfValues` is bound to the child component with a `=` binding and not a `<` binding - changing to a `<` binding makes it suddenly work

The documentation for `$ngChanges` clearly states that it operates with attribute (`'@'`) and one-way (`'<'`) bindings.

From the Docs:

> ### Life-cycle hooks
>
> - `$onChanges(changesObj)` - Called whenever one-way (`<`) or interpolation (`@`) bindings are updated. The `changesObj` is a hash whose keys are the names of the bound properties that have changed, and the values are an object of the form `{ currentValue, previousValue, isFirstChange() }`. Use this hook to trigger updates within a component such as cloning the bound value to prevent accidental mutation of the outer value. Note that this will also be called when your bindings are initialized.
>
> — [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - Life-Cycle Hooks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks)

Two-way (`"="`) binding should be avoided because it adds an extra watcher and it makes migration to Angular 2+ more difficult.

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-based Application Architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture).

Comment: Like I said, I'm aware you need the actual object reference to change - that's why I tried all that second snippet in the OP with a for loop. It still doesn't work (and neither does `Array.concat`). Having done some more playing around, I think this actually has to do with the fact that `listOfValues` is bound to the child component with a `=` binding and not a `<` binding - changing to a `<` binding makes it suddenly work.

Comment: @JackM The documentation for `$ngChanges` clearly states that it operates with attribute (`'@'`) and one-way (`'<'`) bindings. See update to the answer.